# Allow Windows service account to interact with desktop

Tags: c#, winapi, service

(Yes I know this is generally a bad idea - I'm happy that in this particular case the risks are mitigated by other means)

I have a C# service which needs to interact with the user desktop. 
This has been working fine with the service running as LocalSystem with the 'allow service to interact with desktop' option checked. `System.Environment.UserInteractive` is `True` and the rest of the service works fine.

However now I want to run the service under a Service Account so I can lock down permissions better. The service is running as TestAccount and I have added the interactive flag 0x100 to the service type. 
Now `System.Environment.UserInteractive` is `False` .

What am I missing?

Comment: The best bet is to have the service start a Win32 application under administration account and inter-communicate.

Comment: @mic: You can run the client application under a regular user account. You don't need elevated rights to communicate with a service application.

Comment: @michael i guess I can re-do it like that but i'm just curious what the underlying problem really is.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/interactive-services Services cannot directly interact with a user as of Windows Vista. Therefore, the techniques mentioned in the section titled Using an Interactive Service should not be used in new code.

Comment: @michael services absolutely can interact with a user, if enabled to do so. I understand why this is a bad idea. I'm just curious why it is possible from a service running as LocalSystem but not from a service account.

Comment: @snow No they cannot because they run in session zero which is a non interactive session. User sessions start at session 1.

Comment: @snowcrash09 they cannot, it is changed since Vista. You did not read the document I mentioned.

Comment: Why is there still an option and checkbox in the UI to interact with desktop if it doesn't work?